# Can there be multiple pending actions in a single record in approval process on same object

Tags: approval-process, process

[image]

I have 2 approval process running on same opportunity record.Now my question is that can there be multiple pending ( means for diff scenarios say) or will the other approval process fire only when the pending approval history record gets either rejected/closed/approved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. A record can only have one active approval process at a time.